# Getting values from SAX attributes when namespaces are involved

Tags: java, xml, sax

I'm using SAX to parse some XML. In my handler's [startElement()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#startElement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.Attributes%29) method I'm trying to read the value of an attribute named `xsi:type` with something like:

```
String type = attributes.getValue("xsi:type");
```

However, it always returns `null`. This works fine for everything else so I'm assuming that it's due to the namespace prefix. How can I get this value?

Answer (score 3):

Probably this can help, try to play a little with this. This will return the names and the value of the attributes found which can be useful to find the name to use to query.

```
if (attributes.getLength() > 0) {
  for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.print  ("name: " + attributes.getQName(i)));
    System.out.println(" value: " + attributes.getValue(i)));  
  }
}
```

Take also a look [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/AttributesImpl.html) and [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/NamespaceSupport.html) check the function: `getURI`

Answer (score 1):

Try asking SAX what it thinks the attribute's qName is:

```
for (int i=0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {
    String qName = attributes.getQName(i);
    System.out.println("qName for position " + i + ":  " + qName);
}
```